# Setting up a Drupal composer package in a non-Drupal site

Tags: php, drupal, composer-php

There's a particular address formatting composer plugin that looked like it would be quite useful for my own project (not Drupal) called `commerceguys/addressing` (https://www.versioneye.com/php/commerceguys:addressing/0.8.4).

So I'm used to composer, and I just required it in my project, but it doesn't seem to functioning like all the other composer packages I'm using. I'm not sure if this has something specifically to do with Drupal, which I only mention because their readme mentions that this is a Drupal module (but because it was availble through composer, I figured it might work). Per their documentation, I am using the following code

```
use CommerceGuys\Addressing\Address;
use CommerceGuys\Addressing\Formatter\PostalLabelFormatter;
use CommerceGuys\Addressing\AddressFormat\AddressFormatRepository;
use CommerceGuys\Addressing\Repository\CountryRepository;
use CommerceGuys\Addressing\Subdivision\SubdivisionRepository;

$addressFormatRepository = new AddressFormatRepository();
$countryRepository = new CountryRepository();
$subdivisionRepository = new SubdivisionRepository();
// Defaults to text rendering. Requires setting the origin country code
// (e.g. 'FR') through the constructor or the setter, before calling format().
$formatter = new PostalLabelFormatter($addressFormatRepository, $countryRepository, $subdivisionRepository, 'FR', 'fr');

$address = new Address();
$address = $address
    ->withCountryCode('US')
    ->withAdministrativeArea('CA')
    ->withLocality('Mountain View')
    ->withAddressLine1('1098 Alta Ave');

echo $formatter->format($address);
```

But this is giving me this error

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'CommerceGuys\Addressing\AddressFormat\AddressFormatRepository' not found in /media/sf_domains/coolproject.com/public_html/coolfile.php on line 8

There doesn't seem to be any problem with the install, all the "commerceguys" files are in their correct location in the "vendor" folder. I do have ~6 or so other things installed through composer that are working without any issues. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well actually it looks like their documentation is just plain incorrect when it comes to the "use" clauses. After searching for them manually in the files themselves, I came up with

```
use CommerceGuys\Addressing\Model\Address;
use CommerceGuys\Addressing\Formatter\DefaultFormatter;
use CommerceGuys\Addressing\Repository\AddressFormatRepository;
use CommerceGuys\Addressing\Repository\CountryRepository;
use CommerceGuys\Addressing\Repository\SubdivisionRepository;
```

which is actually working great now.